# When should I use const in C++ constructor parameters?

Tags: c++, coding-style

I am with doubt regarding clean code/coding style, the doubt is, when should I use the keyword `const` in C++ constructor parameters. For example, consider the following class:

```
class A {
    public:
    B& b;
    explicit A (const B& b_): b(b_) {}
    };
```

In this code, I want to initialize the reference `b` from the class `A`, and at the same time, I want to express that the reference passed as a parameter to the class `A` constructor will not be used to change the values of the object `b_`. However, the presented code will not compile, and the compiler will present the message:

```
"error: binding reference of type ‘B&’ to ‘const B’ discards qualifiers"
```

I know I can use the keyword `const` in the `b` class attribute, however, it will make the attribute constant, and I do not want to impose this constraint over the attribute. So, I would like to know what should I do in this situation.

Comment: Use `const` whenever possible.

Comment: You can't promise `b_` won't change what it refers to *and* pass `b_` to `b` *and* retain the rights to modify what `b` refers to. This is a contradiction. This expresses you both want to be able to modify `b_` and also promise not to modify `b_`.

Comment: Ok, so in this case, I must remove the `const` from the constructor parameter, that's it?

Comment: FWIW, reference class member are not ideal. They stop the assignment operators from being generated.  I would switch to a pointer (smart or otherwise).

Comment: "*I want to express that the reference passed as a parameter to the class `A` constructor will not be used to change the values of the object `b_`.*" But if you **ever** want to modify that reference to `b_` (and so modify `b_`), you can't take it as `const`.

Comment: @MatheusDiógenesAndrade It depends on what you actually want to do. Right now your stated goal is a contradiction and the first step is to resolve it. Once you know what you want, you can decide whether to add `const` to `b`, remove `const` from `b_` or change your design.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, and scohe001, now I see, thank you.

Comment: @MatheusDiógenesAndrade I would recommend paying attention to NathanOliver's comment. Most of the time, if you use a reference member, you will eventually come to regret it. Using a pointer is usually better than references when it comes to class data members.

Comment: But, if I put the word `const` in the `b` class attribute, will I be able in the future to change the value of reference `b`? (I am not asking if I will be able to change the object of the referece `b`).

Comment: @MatheusDiógenesAndrade It sounds to me like you are asking if you can change *which* object `b` refers to vs changing the value of the object currently being referred. One thing to understand about references in c++ is that once they are initialized it is impossible to change *which* object they refer to. If you want to do that you need to use a pointer instead. Edit : You may be interested in [What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const).

Comment: @MatheusDiógenesAndrade Your questions make me think you may want to read a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list#388282). It seems you don't know the language well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to express that the reference passed as a parameter to the class A constructor will not be used to change the values of the object b_.

But that's not true. The reference passed to `A`'s constructor can be modified. Not *necessarily* by `A`'s constructor directly, but by whatever other member functions of `A` which modify the object.

If a function takes a parameter by `const&`, the caller of that function has the right to expect that the object will not be modified by that function or by any process *dependent* on that function's execution. Such as initializing a reference member in a constructor which can be accessed after that constructor's execution.

What you should do is not lie to the user. A dependent result of `A`'s constructor is that the parameter passed to it may be modified. So it should be a non-`const` reference.

Equally importantly, the act of creating an `A` fundamentally depends on the given object *continuing to exist* after the constructor exits. Since a `const&` parameter can be bound to a temporary, it would be very easy for someone to call your constructor like this `A a(B{})`; `a` after this statement references an object that has been destroyed. If your function took a non-`const` reference, this would be a compile error.